# jQuery draggable isn't draggable after being dropped

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I have two divs, each containing a list of quantities and items. The items are draggable and the div containing the items is droppable. If an item of the same name appears in that div, that item cannot be dropped on that div again. Eventually I will be controlling the number of items that are moved, but I'm just trying to get this part to work for now.

The problem I'm having is that once I drop an item on the div, I can no longer drag it. I've tried adding draggable() to the new item that I am creating, but that just made things weird.

The exact same code worked when I was adding an li to a ul, but I wanted to move just the name of the item and not the quantity, so I am using divs instead of li.

Here is a jsfiddle of my code: http://jsfiddle.net/imjustabill/eJ4KH/

And here are the pertinent parts

```
      $(function () {
        $("#inventory1 .item").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#inventory2").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var item = ui.draggable.attr("data-item");
                var qty = ui.draggable.attr("data-qty");
                var itemDesc = ui.draggable.text();
                if (!$(this).find("[data-item='"+item+"']").length) {
                    $("<div class='qty'></div>").text(qty).appendTo(this);
                    $("<div class='item ui-draggable' data-qty='"+qty+"' data-item='"+item+"'></div>").text(itemDesc).appendTo(this);
                }
            }
        });

        $("#inventory2 .item").draggable({
            appendTo: "body",
            helper: "clone"
        });
        $("#inventory1").droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var item = ui.draggable.attr("data-item");
                var qty = ui.draggable.attr("data-qty");
                var itemDesc = ui.draggable.text();
                if (!$(this).find("[data-item='"+item+"']").length) {
                    $("<div class='qty'></div>").text(qty).appendTo(this);
                    $("<div class='item ui-draggable' data-qty='"+qty+"' data-item='"+item+"'></div>").text(itemDesc).appendTo(this);
                }
            }
        });
    });

<div id="inventory1">
<h4>Inventory 1</h4>
    <div class="qty">7</div><div class="item" data-qty="7" data-item="item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="qty">5</div><div class="item" data-qty="5" data-item="item2">Item 2</div>
    <div class="qty">2</div><div class="item" data-qty="2" data-item="item3">Item 3</div>
    <div class="qty">9</div><div class="item" data-qty="9" data-item="item4">Item 4</div></div>

<div id="inventory2">
<h4>Inventory 2</h4>
    <div class="qty">4</div><div class="item" data-qty="4" data-item="item1">Item 1</div>
    <div class="qty">2</div><div class="item" data-qty="2" data-item="item5">Item 5</div></div>
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is, that the Draggable calls it's destroy() on drop so you loose your dragging ability. One dirty way is to make your dropped element draggable again:

```
$("#inventory2").droppable({
  drop: function (event, ui) {
    var item = ui.draggable.attr("data-item");
    var qty = ui.draggable.attr("data-qty");
    var itemDesc = ui.draggable.text();
    if (!$(this).find("[data-item='"+item+"']").length) {
      $("<div class='qty'></div>").text(qty).appendTo(this);
      $("<div class='item ui-draggable' data-qty='"+qty+"' data-item='"+item+"'></div>").text(itemDesc).draggable({appendTo: "body", helper: "clone"}).appendTo(this);
    }
  }
});
```

But it won't be droppable again.

Do you have to use draggable/droppable?
Just use jQueryUI's own **Sortable with connected lists**. Its already perfectly implemented to jQueryUI:
[jQueryUI Sortable with connected lists](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Comment: This is perfect. It works perfectly. It does seem to be droppable again. Not with my current code, because I am not allowing duplicates, but in the long term that isn't the behavior I'm looking for. Once I took out the requirement of it being unique, it worked perfectly. 

Thank you!

Comment: I have a question on your answer, if you'd be so kind. I tried making the dropped element draggable by changing the code for the new div I was creating to this: `$("<div class='item ui-draggable' data-qty='"+qty+"' data-item='"+item+"'></div>").text(itemDesc).draggable().appendTo(this);` but it just gave very weird results. Why does yours work?

Comment: @user1118374 You forgot to pass your Settings `{appendTo:"body",helper:"clone"}`. Your Element should be draggable without passing it, but jQueryUI will mess up the positioning and Domtree because it uses some standardsettings that won't fit your Domtree and stylesettings. `$("<div class='item ui-draggable' data-qty='"+qty+"' data-item='"+item+"'></div>").text(itemDesc).draggable({appendTo:"body",helper:"clone"}).appendTo(this);` should work fine again.